# My form styling won't load

Tags: html, css

My web page loads with no styling on the inputs. When I put the styling inside the HTML file it displays correctly. I tried adding it before and after the scripts however nothing is working. I don't want to put the styling inside the same file.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Article Review</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="background-image"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <form method="POST" id="form">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="First" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name: " />
            <input type="text" id="lastname" autocomplete="Last" placeholder="Last Name: " />
            <input type="text" id="user" autocomplete="User" placeholder="Username: " />
            <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password: " />
            <input type="email" autocomplete="Email" id="email" placeholder="Email: " />
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Next here is my CSS:

```
#background-image {
background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
}

input[type=text], select {
width: 100%;
padding: 12px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
width: 100%;
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
padding: 14px 20px;
margin: 8px 0;
border: none;
border-radius: 4px;
cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Css and html file are located in the same folder?

Comment: try close your link tag like this: <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the location of your CSS relative to your HTML document, on your server.

Try relocating your `index.css` file to the root directory of your web server, and then make the following change to your HTML:

```
<!-- Add / infront of index.css, and close your link tag with />  -->
<link href="/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me using chrome.

Make sure the index.css is in the same folder as your html file

You could also try:

```
<link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

***index.css***, ***index.html*** must be on the same directory. 
If you still have the same issue.
I suggested you to hard reload your page (Ctrl+Shift+R).